# Select rows where a field from another column can take two values

Tags: postgresql

**Table data:**

| id | servicetype | value | taxid | customerid | comment | docid | itemid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1451806 | 1 | -56.10 | 2 | 6788 | Monthly subscription 04/2023 (Internet - AlfaNET 500/500 w pakiecie) | 730818 | 1 |
| 1451807 | 5 | -53.90 | 3 | 6788 | Monthly subscription 04/2023 (Telewizja - AlfaTV pakiet Plus Korzystny) | 730818 | 2 |
| 1451808 | 5 | -15.00 | 3 | 6788 | Monthly subscription 04/2023 (Telewizja - Multiroom 2021) | 730818 | 3 |
| 1451809 | 1 | -59.90 | 2 | 6789 | Monthly subscription 04/2023 (Internet - AlfaNET 300/300) | 730819 | 1 |

**Questions:**

1. Select all rows where field customerid must have at least two rows which includes at least one row with taxid=2 and taxid=3 all has the same docid

Example:
for customerid=10 there exist at least one row with taxid=2 and taxid=3 and all of them has docid=1234

2. Then sum **value** the previously selected rows depending on the TAXID value.

Comment: #1) I'm no DB expert. My main problem is part when I must select only curomersid where it must contains at least one row with taxid=2 and taxid=3 #2) customerid=10 is just example. I need all customers where condition with taxid is met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery to identify the customerid and docid of interest, then join it with the table to get the sum for every taxid:

```
SELECT customerid, docid, taxid, SUM(value)
FROM table 
JOIN (SELECT customerid, docid
      FROM table
      GROUP BY customerid, docid
      HAVING COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE taxid=2) > 0 
         AND COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE taxid=3) > 0) AS t2 
ON (table.customerid = t2.customerid and table.docid = t2.docid)
GROUP BY customerid, docid, taxid
```

If you only need a total for those two values of taxid, you can use this query, without group by:

```
SELECT SUM(value) FILTER (WHERE taxid=2) as vat23, 
       SUM(value) FILTER (WHERE taxid=3) as vat8
FROM table 
JOIN (SELECT customerid, docid
      FROM table
      GROUP BY customerid, docid
      HAVING COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE taxid=2) > 0 
         AND COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE taxid=3) > 0) AS t2 
ON (table.customerid = t2.customerid and table.docid = t2.docid);
```

Answer (score 0):

With https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/324470/63340 answer my final query looks like that. Don't know if it's optimal but works as expected.

```
WITH cashvat (vat23, vat8) AS
  (SELECT c.customerid,
          c.docid,
          c.taxid,
          SUM(c.value) AS suma
   FROM cash c
   JOIN
     (SELECT cc.customerid,
             cc.docid
      FROM cash cc
      GROUP BY cc.customerid,
               cc.docid
      HAVING COUNT(*) FILTER (
                              WHERE cc.taxid=2) > 0
      AND COUNT(*) FILTER (
                           WHERE cc.taxid=3) > 0) AS t2 ON (c.customerid = t2.customerid
                                                            AND c.docid = t2.docid)
   GROUP BY c.customerid,
            c.docid,
            c.taxid)
SELECT SUM(CASE
               WHEN taxid=2 THEN suma
               ELSE 0
           END) AS vat23,
       SUM(CASE
               WHEN taxid=3 THEN suma
               ELSE 0
           END) AS vat8
FROM cashvat
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a *single scan* of the base table, using conditional aggregation. No joins are needed.

```
SELECT
  d.customerid,
  d.docid,
  SUM(d.value) FILTER (WHERE d.taxid = 2) AS total2,
  SUM(d.value) FILTER (WHERE d.taxid = 3) AS total3  
FROM data d
GROUP BY
  d.customerid,
  d.docid
HAVING COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE d.taxid = 2) > 0
   AND COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE d.taxid = 3) > 0;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/oAqKZod_)

The exact grouping you want is somewhat unclear, you may want to modify.